# c++ compare unsigned int against one in if-statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
unsigned int test=1;

if(test) 
{
   //do something
}
if(test==1)
{
   //do something
}
```

These two if-conditions are equivalent, right?
I am currently debugging a bigger program, where this makes a difference. But it should have no side effects, right?

Comment: No, these are not equivalent. `if(test)` and `if(test != 0)` would be equivalent.

Comment: They are equivalent with the provided initialization only. But if `test` is initialized to any other (than `1`)  non-zero value they won't be.

Comment: Why would they be not equivalent then?

Comment: @Simon Because `test != 0` is not equivalent to `test == 1`. There are over four billion cases where the first is true but the second isn't.

Comment: Because if `test` is `2`, then what will happen?

Comment: What do you mean? `if(test)`  will run if `test` is `1`, `5`, `42` or `4294967295`. `if(test == 1)` will only run if `test` is `1`.

Comment: Of course. test is initialized with either zero or one. If zero, the if-statement should NOT be excecuted and if one it should. That said, both variants in my question achieve this, right?

Comment: Yes, if `test` is only ever `0` or `1`, then these two `if` statements will have the same behaviour. But if you want to limit yourself to two values, I suggested using the right type for that - `bool`.